# replace Regular Expression by a modified version of the Regular Expression result

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

So I am trying to locate and replace all the color values of a css by a modified version of themselves. In this case, I am concentrating on all color codes with the same values.

Replace #333333 by #333.

My code is the following:

```
var regex = textCssMini1.replace(/\#\d{6}/g,"$1");
```

My code allows me to locate the #333333 and replaces it by $1. However I want to replace it by #333.

NB: Multiple instances of color codes exist in my string such as #000000, thus I want to apply it to any possibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following regex with capturing group **[`replace(/#([\da-f])\1([\da-f])\2([\da-f])\3/ig, "#$1$2$3")`](https://regex101.com/r/lU7mG4/1)**

```js
var textCssMini1 = '#111111 #123456 #ffffff #225588 #235588 #333333 #gggggg ( not valid color code )';

var regex = textCssMini1.replace(/#([\da-f])\1([\da-f])\2([\da-f])\3/ig, "#$1$2$3");

document.write(regex);
```

**[Regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/lU7mG4/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Works perfectly and covers also the issue about letters with the color codes. Thank you very much :) I am new to coding and its bloody hard, but this allows me to see a bit of light :)

Comment: @alexanderjanet : glad to help

Answer (score 1):

how about this 
`var regex = textCssMini1.replace(/\#(\d){6}/g,"#$1$1$1");`

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
var regex = textCssMini1.replace(/#([\da-f])\1{5}/ig,"#$1$1$1");
```

*JS Demo*

```js
var textCssMini1 = '#111111 #123456 #ffffff';
var regex = textCssMini1.replace(/#([\da-f])\1{5}/ig,"#$1$1$1");
document.write(regex);
```

If you want to replace each `RGB` values separately

```
var regex = textCssMini1.replace(/#([\da-f])\1([\da-f])\2([\da-f])\3/ig,"#$1$2$3");
```

Answer (score 1):

This should by what you need:

```
var regex = textCssMini1.replace(/\#(.)\1(.)\2(.)\3/i,"#$1$2$3");
```

Matches only if the is a string with a # char followed by 3 sequence of 2 identical characters, and if matches get replaced by a char followed by the 3 sigle characters.

#225588 > #258 (replaced)

#235588 > #235588 (not replaced)

#333333 > #333 (replaced)

Test:

```js
var tomin =document.querySelector('#tominify').innerHTML;

var minified = tomin.replace(/\#(.)\1(.)\2(.)\3/ig,"#$1$2$3");

document.querySelector('#minicolor').innerHTML=minified;
```

```html
Sample css to test regex minify colors:
<p id="tominify">
test1 {
        color: #442299;
        background-color: #442279;
}

test2 {
        color: #333333;
        background-color: #111112;
}
</p>
<p id='minicolor'>
</p>
```